# How to turn off computer after rendering?

Tags: rendering

What is the easy way to turn off the computer automatically after blender completed a render* and saving that render?

My computer is not a monster, that would be helpfull so i can render at night

Comment: Render from the [command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/index.html) using some shell script (like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039845/how-to-shudown-a-computer-using-python)) to shutdown after running render. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10  And i have no idea of what is command line and same for the shell script thingy : P

Comment: Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=46&v=GbGeF56yrm0 and this is the addon link https://yadi.sk/public?hash=gap59AvwMsS7Ew%2B9qSuzKr3AFTEE4gNJwWt5Jzh0jE8%3D

Comment: You may have no idea what the command line is, but that shouldn't stop you from clicking on batFINGER's link and reading the resources, they're very well explained.

Answer (score 3):

The [Alarm and Shutdown](https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-alarm-and-shutdown/609848) add-on can be used.

Alternatively, you can render your scene from the [command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/workflows/command_line.html), and then add a command to shutdown after it completes (or fails).

On Windows this would be something like:

`"C:\path\to\blender.exe" -b "C:\path\to\your file.blend" -a && shutdown -t 0 -s -f`